# Does “The father regretted to tell his children something embarrassing” make sense?

Tags: grammar

I came across this question in a test:

> The father regretted _____ his children how he regretted _____ hard when he was young.
>   A. to tell; not to study
>   B. telling; not studying
>   C. to tell; not studying
>   D. telling; not to study

I know it’s either B or C and I’m inclined towards B. But can “regretted to tell” mean telling something embarrassing here?

Comment: *He remembered to tell ... ; he remembered telling ... ; he regretted telling ...* are all fine, but *he regretted to tell* is not. I am not sure how to explain this in terms of grammar, but it doesn’t sound correct !

Comment: @k1eran has it absolutely right. Whereas _remember_ can take either an infinitive or a gerund complement clause as object, _regret_ can only take gerunds; with an infinitive, it produces ungrammatical sentences. Every verb that can take a complement clause has its own set of affordances -- clause types that are required, optional, or forbidden -- and they all have to be learned individually.

Comment: I regret to  inform you that Mr. Lawler is not quite correct in his opinion. Moreover, _we regret to inform you_ is fairly ingrained in the popular mind, and can be used outside of official communications in a way that connotes the falseness of the sentiment being expressed.

Comment: There's something quite strange with "regret". In its present tense the infinitives it's mostly followed by are to inform/tell/say/advise, but you can also find "to hear", "to disagree", and "to interrupt", common to a greater or lesser extent. So it seems to acceptably take some infinitive verbs but not others. In other words I have no idea which infinitive verbs can and can't be used with it.

Answer (score -2):

It’s C.

He regretted to tell his children.

Because we commonly say ‘I regret to tell you that your application has not been successful’ or whatever.

And it’s ‘not studying’ because it was continuous - the not studying went on for a while.

And yes - he could feel embarrassed about it - ‘regret to tell’ means ‘sorry to tell them’ - about his own wrong-doing, so he might feel ashamed or embarrassed that he was not innately a good example to them.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/i-we-regret-to-inform-tell-you-that

Comment: Sorry but the correct answer is B because the question sentence is in the past tense. The example you give, "We regret to inform you...", is in the present tense. If a person who had said "we regret to inform you that.." later referred back to the previous occasion they would say either "we regretted having informed you" or, more commonly, "we regret _having_ to inform you that..."

Comment: ‘He regretted to tell them’ is in the past tense. So I’m not sure what you’re saying here.

Comment: I'm saying that the past tense of a verb is usually followed by the present participle of any second verb whereas the present tense is usually followed by the infinitive of a second verb. For example "I regretted saying" and "I regret to say". This means that invoking "I regret to say" as an argument  that "I regretted to say" is correct does not hold.

Comment: @BoldBen No, not usually. This is a peculiarity of _regret_: present-tense forms can take either infinitive or gerund complement clauses (with slightly different meanings), but past-tense forms can only take gerunds. This does not hold for other verbs, though: _prefer_ can take both infinitives and gerunds in any tense; _enjoy_ can take only gerunds in any tense; and _want_ can take only infinitives in any tense. The sort of ‘split’ licensing we see with _regret_ is not the norm.

Comment: However, Ben is right that the only correct option here is B, not C. With an infinitive, _regret_ means something like ‘be about to [verb], but feel bad about it’; with a gerund, it means ‘wish you hadn’t [verb]ed, but it’s done so you can’t change it’. The former is pretty much exclusively used in the simple present tense, whereas the latter is freely usable in all tenses. The example in this question is past tense and carries the latter meaning, not the former, so it must be the gerund, not the infinitive.